# How do I stop getting email “Expanding your Reputation” from SO Careers?

Tags: support, jobs, invitation

I have received two emails with subject "Expanding your Reputation" from "Stack Overflow Careers 2.0" <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com>.  The body is similar to:

> In recognition of your contributions to Stack Overflow, we’d like to
>   invite you to create a professional profile on [Stack Overflow Careers
>   2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/invitation/invitation-random-hash-goes-here?campaign=HouseInvite).
>
> A Careers 2.0 profile is a great place to showcase your professional
>   work as a programmer – Stack Exchange answers, open source projects,
>   even the books you’ve read.
>
> Click here to accept the invitation. It’s free!
>
> Even if you’re not looking for a new career today, your Careers 2.0
>   profile will be your professional home on the web. It lets your
>   colleagues, friends, and peers know who you are and what great work
>   you’re doing. It’s a terrific way to build your professional
>   reputation and take your career to the next level. And it’s fun!
>
> You’ll always have complete control over what’s in your profile, who
>   can see it, and whether or not employers can contact you.
>
> But please act soon: this invitation expires in 14 days, so sign up
>   now!
>
> Even if you decide not to join Careers 2.0, we would like to thank you
>   for all your contributions to Stack Overflow. It wouldn’t be the same
>   without you.
>
> Best wishes,
>
> The Stack Overflow team
>
> ---
>
> > > If you found someone great, or found a great job, we'd love to hear
> > >       your story. Email us at careers@stackoverflow.com to let us know how
> > >       it went!
> > >
> > > This mail was sent by careers.stackoverflow.com. Questions? Comments?
> > >       Let us know on [our feedback site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Stack Exchange Inc. 55 Broadway,
> > >       26th Floor, NY NY 10006 <3
> > >
> > > If you would like to opt out of future emails, please [click here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/email/optout/email.address@here/hash-here).

I do not know why I received them, but I am not interested in them at all and I do not want to receive more.  How can I stop them?

Comment: Maybe that's the first network-wide phishing scam? Stealing people's SE credentials to place huge bounties on scammers' questions?

Comment: Ah, no, it seems [legit.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe/6281337384/in/photostream)

Comment: Click on the Opt Out link at the bottom?

Comment: Nice, @The, that's more information than the question provides!

Comment: @chown: That seems to be the answer.  Thanks!  Can you post it as answer or should I do it?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Too late, oh well =).

Comment: @chown: Ah, broken moderators on MSO as always.  Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 9):

This is a one-time email invitation to create a profile on Careers, sent to users who are active on Stack Overflow.  If you received two it probably means you have duplicate accounts somewhere on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "We’re impressed by your “c#” tag answers on Stack Overflow. In recognition of your generous spirit, we’d like to invite you to create a professional profile on Stack Overflow Careers 2.0.". Are you really impressed or are you just being nice? Do you really look at peoples answers or have some bot that sends it after person gets X upvotes or accepted answers?

Comment: -1 Wrong, it's a two-times at least.